# how do i put child divs over the parent divs background picture?

Tags: html, css

I´ve been trying to display the child div over the parent div but it keeps it pushing down. i´d like to have the background picture with a banner on top of it with some text inside the banner.

```
<div class="contact-wrapper">
  <div class="contact-background"></div>
    <div class="contact-header">
      <h1>Contact Us</h1>
    </div>
</div>


    .contact-wrapper{
 width: auto;
 height: 400px;
 border: 3px solid #ff0000;
 margin-top: 5px;
}

.contact-background{
 background-image: url("images/background1.jpg");
 width: auto;
 height: 400px;
 object-fit: contain;
 vertical-align: top;
 opacity: 0.7;
 position: relative;


.contact-header{
 width: auto;
 height: 70px;
 background-color: #c1c1c1;
 line-height: 70px;

}
```

Comment: Any reason why you have to have an extra div for the background? can't you just set the background for the container div with CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add

```
position: absolute; top:0;
```

to the `.contact-header` class

```css
.contact-wrapper{
 width: auto;
 height: 400px;
 border: 3px solid #ff0000;
 margin-top: 5px;
}

.contact-background{
 background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/350x350");
 width: auto;
 height: 400px;
 object-fit: contain;
 vertical-align: top;
 opacity: 0.7;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
}

.contact-header{
 width: 100%;
 height: 70px;
 background-color: #c1c1c1;
 position: absolute;
 top:0;
 z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-wrapper">
  <div class="contact-background"></div>
    <div class="contact-header">
      <h1>Contact Us</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi, 
what is does is the following: the width of the header becomes as large as the text "contact us" takes in. the position stays the same. It is still under the background image.

Comment: I replaced "width: auto;" with "width: 100%;" in "contact-header" class

Comment: I edited to code, try to add  "z-index: 1;" on "contact-background" and "z-index: 2;" on contact-header